# Could not autowire. No beans of 'MessagingPropertiesRefactor' type not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, spring-bean

I've seen other questions related to this issue but none of them actually helps with my issue.

I have these two properties defined in my test class.

```
  @Autowired  
  private MessagingProperties messagingProperties;

  @Autowired
  private MessagingPropertiesRefactor messagingPropertiesRefactor;
```

I am trying to create a new version of **MessagingProperties.java**. I basically copied this class and create a new file **MessagingPropertiesRefactor.java** (same package/dir) and pasted the same code. I changed the class definition, etc., but for the most part are the same.

I get an IntelliJ design time compiler error stating that "Could not autowire. No beans of 'MessagingPropertiesRefactor' type not found."

I then searched for every single Usage of the original class to double check if it has been declared somewhere but I have found nothing.

I am "new" to Java (and Spring). Has anyone run into the same issue before?

Comment: does the refactored class have `@Component` annotation? if not you should declare a bean of this class in your beans.xml file or in the AppConfig class file

Answer (score 2):

If your new class **MessagingPropertiesRefactor** is not annotated with `@Component` you have got to declare it either in **beans.xml** like this:

```
<beans>
    <bean name="messagingPropertiesRefactor" class="com.package.path.MessagingPropertiesRefactor"/>
</beans>
```

or in your **AppConfig.java** like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessagingPropertiesRefactor messagingPropertiesRefactor() {
        return new MessagingPropertiesRefactor();
    }
}
```

[Source Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply Spring dependency injection in tests, you have 2 basic options:

1. If you want to have the beans declared in XML, declare both `MessagingProperties` and `MessagingPropertiesRefactor` in XML file and annotate the test class the following way:

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    
   @ContextConfiguration("your.xml")
   ```

   The beans should be successfully autowired.
2. To have the beans declared in JavaConfig, do the following

   2.1. Annotate you test class like this:

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    
   @ContextConfiguration
   ```

   2.2. Inside the test class, define context configuration class that declates the beans that you need:

   ```
   @Configuration    
   static class Config {

       @Bean
       public MessagingProperties messagingProperties() {
           // Assuming MessagingProperties has default ctor.
           return new MessagingProperties();
       }

       // Same for MessagingPropertiesRefactor
   }
   ```

   Enjoy the autowired beans :)
   *The config class does not have to be nested into the test class.

For more info regarding the topic, please consult Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig, Chapter 3.5.4. Context management.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that `MessagingPropertiesRefactor` has all annotations applied to the class that `MessagingProperties` has. If it has, than look for the bean definition of `MessagingProperties`  in xml configurations for your project and make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the "magic" line of code that makes it a "bean".

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({MessagingProperties.class, MessagingPropertiesRefactor.class})
public class MessagingConfiguration {

@Autowired
  private MessagingProperties messagingProperties;

@Autowired
  private MessagingPropertiesRefactor messagingProperties;
```

So, apparently all I needed to do is add this class to the @EnableConfigurationProperties attribute. Then I can use it anywere by using the @Autowired attribute.

Now... why or how, I don't know (like I said, I am "new" to java) and I would love for someone to elaborate on this.

Comment: Are your classes `MessagingPropertie` and `MessagingPropertiesRefactor` annotated as `@ConfigurationProperties`? If so, there is no magic :) As annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties` says, you have enabled them, i.e., registered them as beans.

Comment: However, it does not seem as a good approach to autowire ConfigurationProperties. If you are looking for a technique to autowire beans and work with them like with "normal" objects, i.e., plainly call their methods, then it would probably be better to apply one of the solutions proposed in the answers. Your case might be specific though, but it is not quite clear from the question.